# PHP : How to get repeated character in string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have strings like this :

```
Aaaaaaaaa
```

I want to stop repeating just to 3 times, but not break the lowercase/uppercase, like this :

```
Aaa
```

My regex breaks the lowercase/uppercase :

```
$patternReplace = '/(.)\1{3,}/iu';    
$chaine = preg_replace($patternReplace, '$1$1$1', $chaine, -1 );
```

Result :

```
AAA
```

I want to get :

```
Aaa
```

thanx for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use subpatterns to get the additional backreferences(first subpattern is for the first character, the second subpattern - for the next two identical characters) :

```
$chain = "Aaaaaaaaa";
$patternReplace = '/(.)(\1{2})\1{1,}/iu';
$chain = preg_replace($patternReplace, '$1$2', $chain);

print_r($chain);  // "Aaa"
```